# UI Elements change position after segue creation

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I am creating my first iOS app using Swift.

There is a first viewController with some buttons on it.

I need to navigate to a second viewController when clicking an a button. For that I am creating a segue from the button to the second viewController.

Once the push segue is created, all UI Elements from the second viewController move their position, as shown here:

Before creating the segue:

[image]

And then, once the segue is created:

[image]

You may see that all UI elements from the second view Controller have change their positions.

What should I do to avoid this? What should I take into account to let all elements in the original position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change second view controller presentation style to full screen[image]

Answer (score 1):

you ui elements does not change position, is the new presentation style in iOS 13 that change and the look is different. you could prevent this by two ways.
in storyBoard goes to the secondvc and [image]

select fullScreen or by code after your presentation or is segue

```
   let vc = UIStoryBoard("Main",bundle, nil).instatiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewControllerStoryBoardIdentifier") as! SecondViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

in here come the presentation  if not segue

```
self.present(vc,animated:true)
```

Comment: thank you, your proposal is also right, but I have already accept the answer from another user

Answer (score 0):

Change the presentation to full screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXsFQ.png)

Comment: Hi Drokez, although your response seems to be correct, I suggest you give a more descriptive explanation to the OP. Let's enforce a better learning by giving good answers, that will stick in the heads of those who reach your answer.

Comment: i am new here. i tried attaching a picture with explanation also but i failed. Sorry for that.. :)